# Can a bistatic receiving radar get an echo on different axis?

Tags: rf

I’m a bit confused about bistatic radar. I understand the case when the Tx(transmitter) antenna and Rx(receiver) antenna are separated and and the target (such as a plane) approaches to both of them and they are in alignment of each other.

However, just basic assumption, assume that a ground based transmitter radar antenna (Tx in image) aligned with target’s pitch axis and the airborne receiver radar antenna (on another plane) aligned with target’s roll axis. So, the transmitter antenna hits on the pitch axis of the plane whereas receiving antenna is aligned with roll axis of the plane.

In this case, Can the receiving radar get the echo despite the different axis of the echo?

Thanks for any comment.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> understand the case when the Tx(transmitter) antenna and Rx(receiver) antenna are separated

Indeed! Correct.

> and the target (such as a plane) approaches to both of them and they are in alignment of each other.

There's no requirement on geometry given by the term "bistatic" other than that the receiver and the emitter of the reflected signal are not in the same place.

> Can the receiving radar get the echo despite the different axis of the echo?

Radar targets in general are not corner reflectors, and typically scatter the signal. So, most likely, yes, though the effective radar cross section might be severely reduced.

Comment: If "aligned with the pitch axis" means the transmitted wave is arriving broadside to the fuselage, and "aligned with the roll axis" means the receiving antenna is directly ahead or behind the plane, the return will be relatively weak, as Marcus points out. It will depend on leading and trailing edges of the fuselage, wings, and engine(s) for scattering; the relatively large surface of the fuselage won't participate much.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt Exactly! I got what you and Dear Marcus pointed.Thank you both!